# Querying a post by date (year and month) and slug

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am attempting to create a blog system using Node.js and Express.

Each `article` has a slug, which is saved into the database. For example, `hello-world`. Currently I can access a post with just it's slug, such as `/article/hello-world`.

However, I want the URLs to look more like this: `/article/:year/:month/:slug`. For example, `/article/2011/07/hello-world`. How would I do this? I am using MongoDB's `findOne` method currently, and in the database I have saved a timestamp in a field called `created_at`.

Comment: Is this question actually about how to do the mongodb query, or is it about node.js and how to configure your URL patterns? To me, it seems this question should only be tagged mongodb and has nothing to do with the web app. Also, what does your current query look like?

Comment: It probably should just be tagged onto mongodb, but I wanted to give some context and perhaps some people in those communities have previously dealt with this. So currently my query just looks like this: `articleModel.find({ slug: 'hello-world' }, function () { … });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a date range query:

```
db. article.findOne({
    created_at: { $gte: ISODate("2012-04-01"), $lte: ISODate("2012-04-30") }, 
    slug: "hello-world"
})
```

Your specific client language (node.js in this case) I'm sure provides easier ways to work with the date objects.

Comment: Ah, I see. So we're basically saying find the article within this month. Seems like a working solution, I just need to find out a way of calculating the last day of the month in JavaScript, but I think this answers my question. Thank you.

Comment: Do I have to pass it an ISO date? What about this format: `Tue Jul 31 2012 20:00:14 GMT+0100 (BST)`?

Comment: Are you using Mongoose? I believe you just use the Date object and the driver handles the format for you.

Comment: One alternate solution is to also store a created year and created month int, and index them. If you are going to be doing a ton of queries like this to resolve your posts, it might make it easier in the long run.

Comment: It's a tradeoff between performance and efficiency. More integers in the DB = larger DB, whereas this method will require more calculations. It's for a small blog that will only have a dozen or so requests per day - what would you do?

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh: You are talking about 2x 4-byte int fields per doc. At 1 million documents, thats only a little over 7.5MB. Hardly inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like given the URL with year, month (as int?) and slug you want to query for the first article that matches.

If year is YY, month is MM (1 through 12) the query would be

```
db.article.findOne({slug: "slug", 
          created_at: {$gte: new Date(YY,MM-1), 
          $lt: new Date(YY, MM) })
```

Javascript Date objects have months which are zero based so if you get 01 for January you need to pass 0 to Date to create January 1.